# flatMap() called twice on single event

Tags: swift, mvvm, swift2, rx-swift

I have a `ViewController` in which on the `init()` I create a hot stream using `PublishSubject`. I then pass in the stream to my `ViewModel` using `stream.asObservable()` in the `viewDidLoad()`, as the `ViewModel` has other dependencies which are streams generated from the views, so it has to wait until the binding of the views is finished before creating the `ViewModel`. After creating the `ViewModel` I push an event in my `ViewController` into the stream and then expect the ViewModel to react to the event by firing off an asynchronous request (which has also been wrapped with Rx).

ViewController:

```
class ExampleViewController: ViewController {

    ....

    private let exampleStream: PublishSubject<Bool>

    init() {
        self.exampleStream = PublishSubject<Bool>()
    }

    viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewModel = viewModelFactory.create(exampleStream.asObservable())
        self.exampleStream.onNext(true)
    }

    ....
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ExampleViewModel {

    init(stream: Observable<Bool>) {
        stream.flatMap { _ in
            doSomethingAsyncThatReturnsAnObservable()
        }
    }

    private func doSomethingAsyncThatReturnsAnObservable() -> Observable<CustomObject> { ... }
}
```

My problem is that `doSomethingAsyncThatReturnsAnObservable()` is called twice when only one event is inside the stream. I have checked that fact by using `var count = 1; stream.subscribeNext { _ in print(count++) }` which prints `1`.

Any idea as to why `subscribeNext()` fires once on each event but `flatMap()` fires twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `flatMap` called on every subscription.

If you want it to be called once use `shareReplay(1)`

Comment: thanks :) I did not realise that my ViewModel was still living on scene change as they are just stacking up each other and the current scene was emitting an event that the ExampleViewModel had subscribed to.